# Reusing lambda from a map stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm still learning Java. I have code that looks like:

```
List<String> list = userData.getEmails().stream()  
          .map(email -> codeThatGetsTheHost(email))  
          .peek((email, host) -> {//Only print if email is not null
                System.out.println("email=" + email + " host=" + host);})  
          .collect(Collectors.toList());  //should collect hosts.
```

The above code does not work because the peek() does not have access to the main stream variable, that is email used in map(). How do i fix this?

Comment: Put the `peek()` before the `map()` and you can access `email` (and therefore `host`).

Comment: I updated the code to be clearer. The map is what gives me the host.

Comment: But unless you can get the email from the host, you can't work with a stream of hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Either put `peek` before the `map` to access all the data you need:

```
List<String> list = userData.getEmails().stream()  
          .peek(email -> System.out.println("email=" + email + " host=" + email.getHost())) 
          .map(email -> email.getHost())   
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or perform both actions (completely legal) in the `map` method to avoid repeating the getter call:

```
List<String> list = userData.getEmails().stream()  
          .map(email -> {
               String host = email.getHost();
               System.out.println("email=" + email + " host=" + host));
               return host;
          })
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, i think this will work. So there is no way to reuse the stream variable "email" that was used in map() again in another transform?

Comment: I am not aware of any way. Once you `map` into something new, you lose the original value unless you map into a `Pair`/`Map.Entry`/`Tuple`/whatever, however, it doesn't seem like a good practice in this case since it duplicates data.

Answer (score 1):

You should use peek before mapping emails to their hosts.
This is a sample code for your case:

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


class Email{
    public String email;
    private String host;
    public Email(String email, String host){
        this.email = email;
        this.host = host;
    }
    public String getHost(){
        return host;
    }
}

class UserData{
    List<Email> emails = new LinkedList<>();
    public List<Email> getEmails(){
        return emails;
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      UserData userData = new UserData();
      userData.emails.add(new Email("a@s.com", "host1"));
      userData.emails.add(new Email("b@s.com", "host2"));
      userData.emails.add(new Email("c@s.com", "host3"));
      List<String> list = userData.getEmails().stream()
          .peek(email -> System.out.println("email=" + email + " host=" + email.getHost()))  
          .map(email -> email.getHost())  
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(list);
    }
}

email=Email@7bfcd12c host=host1
email=Email@1c2c22f3 host=host2
email=Email@18e8568 host=host3
[host1, host2, host3]
```